# How to Delete created directory if Jgit clone command failed?

Tags: java, clone, jgit

I have write a simple function to clone repository using Jgit CloneCommand. It works okay. But the local Directory that has been created during the process can't be deleted in case of the cloning process fails for any reason like, wrong username or password. Because the Folder contains an active Git Repository.

I tried "cloneCommand.getRepository().close();"  inside catch block it gives NullPointerException

```
File file = new File(localDirectory("Files/Application"));

CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
        cloneCommand.setURI(repo.getUrl());
        cloneCommand.setDirectory(file);
cloneCommand.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(repo.getUsername(), repo.getPassword()));
try {
    cloneCommand.call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete files recursively with proper order. Some files can be missing shortly (like git locks file), so you need to delete only if the file still exists.

`Git` implements `AutoCloseable`, so it should be used with **try-with-resources** statement.

I will do something like this:

```
try (Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
    .setDirectory(file)
    .call()) {
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    Files.walkFileTree(file.toPath(), new DeleteFileVisitor())
}
```

### `DeleteFileVisitor.java`

```
public class DeleteFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes) throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path directory, IOException ioException) throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(directory);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exception) {
        // log error
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```